# Move an object towards a target in PyBullet

Tags: bulletphysics, bullet

I'm pretty new to PyBullet and physics engines in general.  My first step is trying to get one object to move towards another.

```
import pybullet as p
import time
import pybullet_data

DURATION = 10000

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)#or p.DIRECT for non-graphical version
p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath()) #optionally
print("data path: %s " % pybullet_data.getDataPath())
p.setGravity(0,0,-10)
planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf")
cubeStartPos = [0,0,1]
cubeStartOrientation = p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0,0,0])
boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf",cubeStartPos, cubeStartOrientation)
gemId = p.loadURDF("duck_vhacd.urdf", [2,2,1],  p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0,0,0]) )
for i in range (DURATION):
    p.stepSimulation()
    time.sleep(1./240.)
    gemPos, gemOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(gemId)
    cubePos, cubeOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(boxId)
    oid, lk, frac, pos, norm = p.rayTest(cubePos, gemPos)[0]
    #rt = p.rayTest(cubePos, gemPos)
    #print("rayTest: %s" % rt[0][1])
    print("rayTest: Norm: ")
    print(norm)
    p.applyExternalForce(objectUniqueId=boxId, linkIndex=-1, forceObj=pos
        ,posObj=gemPos, flags=p.WORLD_FRAME)
print(cubePos,cubeOrn)
p.disconnect()
```

But this just gets R2 to wiggle a bit.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are moving a robot, you should do something a little more complicated, by providing some commands to the joints of the robot. [Here is an example](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/robotcontrol.py)

Now assuming that you are moving something less complicated by applying an external force, the simplest thing you can do is multiply a factor `alpha` with the difference between the two positions; this would be your force.

For your example this would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pybullet as p
import time
import pybullet_data

DURATION = 10000
ALPHA = 300

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)  # or p.DIRECT for non-graphical version
p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())  # optionally
print("data path: %s " % pybullet_data.getDataPath())
p.setGravity(0, 0, -10)
planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf")
cubeStartPos = [0, 0, 1]
cubeStartOrientation = p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0, 0, 0])
boxId = p.loadURDF("r2d2.urdf", cubeStartPos, cubeStartOrientation)
gemId = p.loadURDF("duck_vhacd.urdf", [
                   2, 2, 1],  p.getQuaternionFromEuler([0, 0, 0]))
for i in range(DURATION):
    p.stepSimulation()
    time.sleep(1./240.)
    gemPos, gemOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(gemId)
    boxPos, boxOrn = p.getBasePositionAndOrientation(boxId)

    force = ALPHA * (np.array(gemPos) - np.array(boxPos))
    p.applyExternalForce(objectUniqueId=boxId, linkIndex=-1,
                         forceObj=force, posObj=boxPos, flags=p.WORLD_FRAME)

    print('Applied force magnitude = {}'.format(force))
    print('Applied force vector = {}'.format(np.linalg.norm(force)))

p.disconnect()
```